# Simultaneous Requests to PHP Script

Tags: php, request

If the PHP Engine is already in the middle of executing a script on the server what would happen to other simultaneous browser requests to the same script?

- Will the requests be queued?
- Will they be ignored?
- Will each request have its own script
  instance?
- Any other possibility?

Comment: Also check this answer: http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The server, depending on its configuration, can generally serve **hundreds of requests at the same time** -- if using Apache, the **[`MaxClients`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients)** configuration option is the one saying :

> The `MaxClients` directive sets the
>   limit on the number of simultaneous
>   requests that will be served. 
> Any
>   connection attempts over the
>   `MaxClients`  limit will normally be
>   queued, up to a number based on the
>   ListenBacklog  directive. 
> Once a child
>   process is freed at the end of a
>   different request, the connection will
>   then be serviced.

The fact that two clients request the same page is not a problem.

So :

> Will the requests be queued?

No ; except if :

- there is some **lock** somewhere -- which can happen, for instance, if the two requests come from the same client, and you are using **file-based sessions in PHP** : while a script is being executed, the session is "locked", which means the server/client will have to wait until the first request is finished *(and the file unlocked*) to be able to use the file to open the session for the second user.
- the requests come from the same client AND the same browser; most browsers will queue the requests in this case, even when there is nothing server-side producing this behaviour.
- there are more than `MaxClients` currently active processes -- see the quote from Apache's manual just before.

> Will they be ignored?

No : this would mean only one user can use a website at the same time ; this would not be quite nice, would it ?

If it was the case, I could not post this answer, if you where hitting F5 at the same moment to see if someone answered !

*(Well, SO is not in PHP, but the principles are the same)*

> Any other possibility?

Yes ^^

*edit after you edited the OP and the comment :*

> Will each request have its own script
>   instance?

There is no such thing as "*script instance*" : put simply, what's happening where a request to a script is made is :

- the webserver forks **another process** to handle the request *(often, for performance reasons, those forks are made in advance, but this changes nothing)*
- the process reads the PHP script from disk

  - **several processes can do this at the same time** : there is no locking on file reading
  - the file is loaded into memory ; in a distinct memory block for each process
- the PHP file in memory is "*compiled*" to opcodes -- still in memory
- those opcodes are executed -- still from the block of memory that belongs to the process answering your request

Really, you can have two users sending a request to the same PHP script *(or to distinct PHP scripts that all include the same PHP file)* ; that's definitly not a problem, or none of the website I ever worked on would work !

Comment: If multiple simultaneous requests are accessing the same php file what would be the outcome. will the other requests be kept pending or each request will have its own script instance?

Comment: There is no such thing as "script instance" : each request is processed by a distinct process (or thread) ;; the scripts are read from memory/disk, but the same file can be read from many processes at the same time without a problem (at least, on "modern" operating systems -- ie both Windows and Linux)

Comment: This is an excellent answer, where could I learn more details about how PHP works? Any good book for this?

Comment: I don't really know about that : I'm guessing going through the manual, reading articles on the net, questions/answers here and there, and working with PHP for several years are a nice way to learn -- but I can't really recommend any book that would explain exactly how PHP works ;; there are some informations in "Extending and Embedding PHP", but its subject is not to explain how PHP works ;; maybe http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php can help ?

Comment: Perfection ! Helped me a lot !

Comment: Regarding the lock when using file-based sessions, you can use  `session_write_close();` to unlock the script so you don't have to wait for it to complete execution.

Comment: There is no such thing as "script instance". there is and that's the only way to prevent one instance to crash the other

Comment: *"the requests come from the same client AND the same browser; most browsers will queue the requests in this case, even when there is nothing server-side producing this behaviour."* If this was true in 2009, it hasn't been true anymore for a **long** time... Browsers may clamp (maxing at 8 requests or so on desktop, probably fewer on mobile), but certainly not just one at a time.

Answer (score 22):

If 2 clients calls the server at the same time, the server is most probably able to reply both clients almost simultaneously. The clients here I define them to the browser level.

Meaning to say that on the same machine, if you're using 2 browsers to load the same website/page at the same time, both should be loaded at the same time.

however since we're talking about PHP, you need to take special notes about sessions. If your pages use sessions, the server only serve one page at a time. This is because session file will be locked, until a script exits.

Look at this example. The 2 files are loaded from the same session aka same browser same user.

```
      scripta.php requested                 scripta.php served
------+---+---------------------------------+------------------------>
          scripta.php started

               scriptb.php requested           scriptb.php started
---------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+--->
                                                                 scriptb.php served.
```

Notice that scriptb.php is only started after scripta.php is served. this is because when scripta.php started, the session file is locked to other scripts so that scripta.php can write to the session file. When scripta.php completes, the session file is unlocked and thus other scripts are able to use it. Thus scriptb.php will wait until the session file is freed then it will lock the session file and use it.

This process will keep repeating to prevent multiple scripts writing to the same session file causing delays. Thus it is recommended to call [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/session_write_close)() when you are no longer using the session, especially on a website using many iframes or AJAX.

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this myself. Basically you need to call `session_write_close()` to prevent single user locking. Make sure once you call `session_write_close()` you don't try and modify any session variables though. Once you call it, treat sessions as read-only from then on.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are running a very non-standard setup your web server (Apache, IIS, nginx, etc.) will have multiple processes that run PHP separately for each request that comes into the server. Simultaneous requests will be serviced simultaneously.