# How do I configure Apache2 to allow multiple simultaneous connections from same IP address?

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2, config, apache-config

By default, Apache2 seems to allow only 1 connection per IP address.

How do I configure Apache2 to allow multiple simultaneous connections from the same IP address?

Here is my situation:

1. a web app being hosted on a server.
2. a remote client makes an request that may take 15 seconds to complete.
3. the same remote client makes another (independent) request.
4. at present, the 2nd request sits in a queue until the 1st request completes,
   since Apache2 seems to impose a limit of 1 connection per IP address.

How do I override this default behaviour and allow the 2nd request to be processed in parallel?

thanks in advance,
  David Jones

Comment: what platform are you running Apache2 on?

Comment: Have you checked out mod_limitipconn module? - http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn2.html

Comment: definitely weird behavior you're seeing since this doesn't normally happen.  did you do anything odd with the config?

Comment: The problem that the original poster had was not related to apache at all, but PHP sessions. Nevertheless, I suggest that the title and post not be modified, because other readers might have the same misunderstanding and this helps them find the right answer.

Comment: Agree with @cornergraf on keeping the title. I found this post because I was searching for Apache and now know its a PHP issue.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I discovered the answer to my problem.  It turns out others have encountered this difficulty before:

[Simultaneous Requests to PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script)

The key detail is that file-based sessions in PHP cause all requests from the same client to be processed sequentially in a queue, rather than in parallel.

In order to solve this problem, it is necessary to make a call to [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/session_write_close)() in every PHP script as soon as session handling is finished.

-- David Jones

Comment: Thanks for this question and answer - it helped me alot.
BTW - I verified the file-based sessions are the cause of the problem by testing first 2 tabs in the same browser (shared session), then with 1 tab in 2 different browsers (different sessions).