# file_get_contents/curl blocks other clients

Tags: php, apache, curl

I use file_get_contents/curl to get access for one API at the another server from my php script. This API isn't fast and can take up to 10 seconds to respond.

When I try to open 2 pages on my web site at the same time, which uses this API, they loaded one by one, i.e. I need to wait 1st to be loaded before server will start to server request for 2nd page.

I use Apache2 and php under linux.
How I can avoid such behaviour, I don't want to block other clients while one of them access this API. Need help!

Thanks.

Comment: no session can be open twice at the same time. Use `session_write_close();` when you want to free the session for another process or thread.

Comment: I just guessed it…^^ That's the usual problem. And yeah, that one is hard to google…

Comment: Thank you @bwoebi!

Comment: More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506574/how-do-i-configure-apache2-to-allow-multiple-simultaneous-connections-from-same

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There is this PHP library: `http://code.google.com/p/multirequest/` (it's a multithreaded CURL lib).

As another solution, you could write a script that does that in a language that supports threading, like Ruby or Python. Then, just call the script with PHP. Seems rather simple.

Comment: bwoebi described the right solution. This seems to be so hard to find on google and documentation.

Comment: additionally, that doesn't use multiple threads _at all_, it uses non-blocking i/o ...