# SoundManager2.js freezes HTTP while loading sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, soundmanager2

I'm using SoundManager2.js on a project that I'm working on. My application has ajax navigation, which allow me to have sound playing (with SoundManager2.js) while the user navigates between pages.

But, that's not what happens: when SoundManager2.js begins loading a sound, all http connections are frozen. What I mean is that I can't communicate with my server while a sound is loading. As soon as my sound finishes loading, all requests are sent.

I've already searched on Google, but nobody seems to have had this problem. Does anybody have any idea what could cause this kind of behaviour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

After searching for a while, I found out where the problem comes from. It does not come from SoundManager.js. It comes from the PHP session files. In the project I'm working on, you have to be logged in to have access to an audio file with SoundManager. So when SoundManager loads the file, a PHP is run to check if the user is logged in. Thus mean that the session files are locked for as long as the file is not completely loaded. My other calls to the server are not able to complete because PHP can't access the session files.

I found this post which explains a lot:
[How do I configure Apache2 to allow multiple simultaneous connections from same IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506574/how-do-i-configure-apache2-to-allow-multiple-simultaneous-connections-from-same)

Thank you