# Long polling locking up other AJAX calls

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, jquery

I'm looking to do long polling to "push" some data down to the client and I'm also making other unrelated AJAX calls to the server in parallel with the long polling. It appears that my other AJAX calls won't complete until the long poll has received a response (either from a response or timeout). When I step through the Javascript, it appears that the 2nd AJAX request is being sent at the proper time, but the response isn't being received until the long poll request gets a response. Any idea what is going on?

Here is the code for the long polling portion:

Server side:

```
    function getPlaylistTracksIfChanged($playlist_id, $numClientTracks) {
  $reportChange = false;
  for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $numServerTracks = $this->PlaylistTrack->find('count', array(
     'conditions' => array('playlist_id' => $playlist_id)
    )
   );

   if($numClientTracks != $numServerTracks) {
    $reportChange = true;
    break;

   }

   sleep(3);

  }

  if($reportChange) {
   $playlist_tracks = $this->PlaylistTrack->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('playlist_id' => $playlist_id),
    'order' => array('PlaylistTrack.position') 
    )
   );

   $this->set('playlist_tracks', $playlist_tracks);
   $this->layout = false;
   $this->render('show_playlist_tracks_list');

  } else {
   $this->autoRender = false;
   return 'false';
  }

 }
```

Client side:

```
function checkForChangesOnServer() {
 $.post('/getResultsIfChanged/' + playlist_id + '/' + $('#sortable_tracks').children().size(), function(results) {

  if(results == 'false') {
   //alert('no change');
  } else {
   //alert('change');
  }

  checkForPlaylistChangesOnServer();

 });
}
```

And a sample of another AJAX call:

Server side:

```
    function getLibraryTracksStartingWithLetter($user_id, $letter) {
  $results = $this->Track->find(
   'all',
   array(
    'conditions' => array(
     'user_id' => $user_id,
     'OR' => array(
      'Track.artist LIKE' => $letter . '%',
      'Track.name LIKE' => $letter . '%'
     )
    ),
    'order' => array('case when Track.artist = "" then 1 else 0 end', 'Track.artist', 'Track.name')
   )
  );

  $this->set('results', $results);
  $this->layout = false;
  $this->render('show_library_results_list');
 }
```

Client side:

```
    function loadLibraryResultsForLetter(letter) {
 highlightLetterFilter(letter);

 $.post('/getLibraryTracksStartingWithLetter/' + user_id + '/' + letter, function(results) {
  updateLibraryResults(results);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like you experienced the session file lock.

Perform `session_write_close()` (or corresponding function in cakephp) to close the session in the begin of the ajax endpoint.

Comment: @RageZ: every php developer should catch this issue :-)

Comment: make sense now I am thinking about it

Comment: I searched for hours the other day for a solution to this problem. As I was about to do my own SO post about it, this one was among the suggested ones, and it was exactly the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know what session_write_close() does internally? Is it just releasing the file lock similar to flock?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: what actually do you need to know? Get php sources and see?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of session file locks. In CakePHP you can choose other options for session management. You can save sessions in database, in cache etc. So you don't wait for file lock issues.

> The built-in configurations are:
>
> php - Saves sessions with the standard settings in your php.ini file.
>
> cake - Saves sessions as files inside app/tmp/sessions. This is a good
>   option when on hosts that don’t allow you to write outside your own
>   home dir.
>
> database - Use the built-in database sessions.
>
> cache - Use the built-in cache sessions.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration

Of course you can make `session_write_close()`, but you should be sure that no changes needed in session between two page loads.

Similar question: [Simultaneous Requests to PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

it works for **symfony 1.4**. user  `session_write_close();` instead of `$this->getUser()->shutdown();`