# Long polling timeout issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, comet

I'm doing a long poll method chatroom. But it seems that, when a long poll occurs and I refresh the page in chrome OR i try to send another async request everything times out (i.e i cant load my domain again until i close/reopen the browser).

My *client* side code is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(
      function () {
        longPollForMessages();
      },
      500
    );
  });

function longPollForMessages()
{
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {     
        $('#chat_messages').append('<div>'+data.messages+'</div>');

        longPollForMessages();
    }
  });
}
```

And my serverside:

```
while(true) {
      $messages = $db->getMessages();

      if (!$messages || sizeof($messages)==0) {
        sleep(1);
      } else {
        echo '{"message":'.json_encode($messages).'}';
        die();
      }
    }
```

Any ideas? Assume no syntax errors.

Comment: Try putting a `break;` after the `echo` in the serverside code

Comment: Thanks four your answer :) I actually had that but forgot to include in my question code. So that is not the issue.

Comment: Guys, I figured it out from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457178/long-polling-locking-up-other-ajax-calls - php locks a given session until the page is done loading so the second ajax call wasn't able to go through. You have to release the lock by calling   session_write_close();

Comment: You are aware that you send back the message as `message` but access it in your JavaScript with `messages`?

Comment: alex - yeah sorry. i just rewrote the code quickly because i didn't want to paste everything (you probably don't want to read all of it). =)

Comment: @Andy, post an answer with what you say in your comment, and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out from this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/4457178/… - php locks a given session until the page is done loading so the second ajax call wasn't able to go through. You have to release the lock by calling session_write_close();

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have already answered your own question, but I recently had a similar problem and found another way to handle it is to disable the `setTimeout` on ajax call, then restart it on `success`. That way you aren't pinging your server for information when it isn't ready to give it.

Comment: AFAIK, the setTimeout only calls the function once. So you still need to restart the call after a successful request. Can you elaborate a bit more on your answer?