# Long Polling Blocks my other Ajax Requests

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, long-polling

ok I do use an Apache Server and I have the following situations.

1. I have a JScript that sends a XHR request to a long polling PHP file
2. Now the request is long polled for 15 secs
3. Now while the long poll is in progress I try to send another XHR request
4. But the another XHR request timeouts and seems not to reach my Apache server

**now my question is, why this happens?** is this because Apache server uses only a single thread connection for a single client? or because of long polling the connection became persistent other XHR request can't be granted?

my server is a XAMPP 1.8.0 with Apache 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found already the answer here.

I need to use the function below

```
session_write_close();
```

[Long polling locking up other AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457178/long-polling-locking-up-other-ajax-calls)

Comment: Did this really fix it? I thought I had fixed this several times but it turned out to be timing sensitive. Try "Empty cache and Hard Reload" in chrome to see if you *really* fixed it. If the long poll request comes before another (important) request, and the keepalive time is 5 seconds, the important request will block for 5 seconds before it opens another connection. As far as I know, browsers don't implement HTTP pipelining, which is very unfortunate. Even server pushed events (the "new way" to do long polling) has the same issue.