# Is it possible to redirect page, even if there are incomplete ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

I need to implement a cronjob functionality using my application, for this i try to use the ajax post so that it will not affect the page loading time. The problem that I am facing currently is if i need to open another url it happpens only after the successful of the ajax request.

Please anybody Suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to abort your ajax request before opening another url. Example with jQuery:

```
var request= $.ajax({
    url: "test.php"
}).done(function() {
    /* do something */
});

//kill the request
request.abort();
```

You could kill the request everytime a link is clicked, e.g:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    request.abort();
});
```

On the server side concurrent requests aren't queued. However if there is a file lock, e.g. when a php script opens a file for writing, concurrent requests to that file would be queued, and thus the execution of a php script would be stalled.

This has been discussed before:
[Simultaneous Requests to PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script)

It seems that if you use file-based sessions in PHP each `session_start();` would cause a file lock. So doing `session_write_close();` after your work with the session is done would release that lock.

Comment: Thank you, in this whether the execution will stop? what i need is i just need to trigger an action and it has to be taken place in the background

Comment: I also would like to know whether the web-server serializes the request. By disabling that will be a sloution