# Why latency increases when a "while loop" PHP script is called several times?

Tags: javascript, php, loops, low-latency

This pair of scripts shows what I mean:

**client (JS)**

```
$.ping = function(i_max) {
    $.get('ping.php', {
        'i_max': i_max,
        'client_start': Date.now() / 1000
    }).done(function(d){
        console.log(d);
    })
}
```

**server (PHP)**

```
$client_start = $_GET['client_start'];
$server_start = round(microtime(true) * 1000) / 1000;
$diff = $server_start - $client_start;
$i = 0;
$i_max = $_GET['i_max'];
while($i < $i_max) {
    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
echo "i_max = $i_max => diff = $diff\n";
```

When few instances are run latency is good, beyond, latency goes bad, is there an option to set in php.ini? Here is a console screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what are you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you using as your webserver? It may only be handling one request at a time, so your `$.ping(0)` must wait until the `$.ping(10)` calls have finished first.

Comment: @strangeqargo concurrent requests that wait for a data to be available on the server in a while loop

Comment: Chrome can't be a web server. Where is your PHP code?

Comment: @slugonamission sorry, apache2

Comment: I'm not blaming the browser, I'm blaming your web server. Anyway, potentially have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script for more information.

Comment: how many threads are "more than a few"?

Comment: @strangeqargo on my localhost, above 2, on an amazon server, more than 5

Comment: seems it's bound to cpu cores, you should try to test your script with nginx or change apache's mpm module (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-vs-nginx-practical-considerations)